# Contornar bloqueio de FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-aws, ftp, heroku

Olá!

Preciso realizar a importação de um arquivo .zip proveniente de um servidor FTP brasileiro. Funciona perfeitamente em minha máquina de desenvolvimento, tanto utilizando o Net/Ftp nativo do Ruby quanto utilizando o wget do linux, o problema é que não funciona no meu ambiente de produção no Heroku, dá time out na conexão: "Connecting to ftp.xxxxxx.com.br (ftp.xxxxxx.com.br)|xxxx.xx.xxx.xxx|:21...". Também já testei utilizando o wget em uma máquina virtual na Digital Ocean e o problema persistiu.

Diante do presente erro, só posso concluir que o servidor não aceita conexões de IP fora do Brasil.

Alguma sugestão para contornar o problema? Estou pensando em contratar um host aqui no Brasil ou mesmo criar uma instância EC2 da Amazon  na Região de São Paulo (o Ip será Nacional neste caso?) só pra hospedar uma API que faça o download desse arquivo e em seguida, salve no Amazon S3, onde tenho pleno acesso aos arquivos.

Alguma sugestão melhor de como contornar o problema?

Comment: Não sei se de fato o problema é esse, mas se "por motivos de segurança" seu provedor bloqueia acesso internacional, sinal que você pode estar comprando gato por lebre (ja vi acontecer, mas com hospedagem bem precária).

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Bacco. O servidor FTP é de terceiros e eu não tenho como alterar suas configurações de forma alguma. Meu ponto é: como conseguir um serviço com Ip brasileiro para, ao menos, baixar o arquivo .zip e subir para o Amazon S3.

Comment: agora, veja se é isso mesmo, pois pode ser outra coisa e eu estar massacrando um "provedor inocente" de maneira injusta :) - a propósito, tente direto por IP pra ver se não é problema de DNS.

Comment: Se o problema for mesmo o IP, pesquise por Proxy. Use ou configure um proxy no Brasil e veja se resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que é um **fato** não poder simplesmente adicionar o IP de seu Server à lista branca do Firewall do servidor onde está o arquivo, você precisará configurar, em um servidor qualquer localizado no Brasil, o port forward via ssh.

O esquema ficará assim:

```
Meu Servidor => Meu servidor de outra coisa que empresta uma conexão ssh => destino
```

Nesta pergunta https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38755/how-to-download-a-file-through-an-ssh-server você pode ver um exemplo usando `wget`

Ips de instâncias EC2 em SP muitas vezes recebem endereços de fora.

Comment: Já implementei a solução através de uma instância Amazon EC2 em SP. Obrigado pela Colaboração